# Correct syntax for \text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, syntax

In some contexts, I see the `\text` command used as follows:
`$ A_\text B $` , which renders correctly as italics A subscripted by a roman B. However, I recall that I "read somewhere" that the proper usage is `$A_\text{B}$` or even `$A_{\text{B}}$`. In particular, I note that importing packages like `breqn` introduces errors in the first and second cases.

What is correct, and why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! _Always_ use braces! The correct is `$A_{\text{B}}$`, and all others work by “accident”

Comment: It's just a happy coincidence that the first two versions work. Don't rely on it and use braces.

Comment: Not using braces when not needed is far more elegant. Moreover in this context you should use `mathrm` rather than `text`

Comment: Actually ... `\text` should never even be used for this, it is the wrong command, `\text` does not do what you think it does, here use `$A_{\mathrm{B}}` if `B` is suppose to be upright. Never `\text` for this

Comment: @Blincer braces is always better than having to explain to users what it works without braces in some cases and not in other cases. Better to be consistent with the use of braces. Also no-one have guaranteed that the unbraced versions of some commands will always keep workling like that.

Comment: I don't agree, that would be like asking children to always put brackets when they do calculations. You write 2*(3+2) not (2)*((3)+(2)). And yes, the version without brackets will still work if there is nothing to bundle.

Comment: As I note, omitting braces can break the code with some packages. Thus, I lean towards always using braces.

Comment: @daleif I think `\text` does what I think it does. Why is `\mathrm` preferred? This command preserves math spacing rules, and that looks really odd if the subscript is a phrase, name or similar, and not a mathematical symbol.

Comment: @JasTer  So you are expecting this outcome: `\textit{test $A_{\text{B}}$ text}` that that is why either `\mathrm` or even `\textrm` is preferred over `\text`. The output of `\text` corresponds to the text out side math, so if that text is italic, so is the outout of `\text`. Ergo if `B` is suppose to he upright in all contexts, `\text` cannot be used and generally newer should be used for anything by textual commetns in displayed math. What you are doing here is more of a textual index (like in `$A_{\textrm{max}}$`, since there it is a phrase, I would use `\textrm` not `\mathrm`)

Comment: @daleif Ok, I see! Did not realize that. Thank you! So `\textrm` is preferred in cases where the subscript is a phrase.

Comment: @JasTer I've been meaning to write an overview article about `\text` for year now. Whether one uses `\mathrm` or `\textrm` or even `\textnormal` depends a bit on your language. Say I want to mark the radius of a circular lake in Danish, I'd write `$R_{\textrm{sø}}$` because `ø` cannot be used in math mode and thus is not usable for `\mathrm`. If you're writing in English, it might be irrelevant whether one used `\mathrm` or `\textrm`